# How to modify TestNG assertEquals?

Tags: testng, assert, assertions

I have actual and expected objects each containing some data members. For one data member, I need to do a contains check instead of equals check and for the rest, equals check is done. Is there a way to do this ?

Comment: There is no smart way of making assertEquals to identify and make check on its own, you will have to handle this programmatically via your code.

Answer (score 0):

Not implicitly, but you have at least the following 2 options:

- use TestNG's `assertTrue`
- use an additional library such as [Hamcrest](https://code.google.com/archive/p/hamcrest/wikis/Tutorial.wiki), [AssertJ](http://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/), etc

**Dependencies:**

```xml
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
        <artifactId>hamcrest-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.3</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.assertj</groupId>
        <artifactId>assertj-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.9.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

**Code:**

```java
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;
import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.*;
import static org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat;
import static org.testng.Assert.assertTrue;

public class MyTest {

    @Test
    public void shouldCheckStringContains() {
        String myString = "This is my string";

        // TestNG
        assertTrue(myString.startsWith("This") 
                && myString.contains("is") 
                && myString.contains("my") 
                && myString.endsWith("string"));

        // Hamcrest
        assertThat(myString, allOf(startsWith("This"),
                                   containsString("is"),
                                   containsString("my"),
                                   endsWith("string")));

        //AssertJ
        assertThat(myString).startsWith("This")
                            .contains("is")
                            .contains("my")
                            .endsWith("string");
    }
}
```